# How to Select multiple elements between two specific elements in xml file with XSL 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to extract few elements in between two elements in an xml with XSL and write the extracted content in to xml file.

I have below XML.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
    <element_1>
      <h1>title</h1>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td />
         </tr>
      </table>
      <h1>Another Title</h1>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td/>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td/>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <h1>Some other Title</h1>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td/>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td/>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      <p>paragraph</p>
   </element_1>
   <element_2/>
</root>
```

XSL is new to me and facing difficulty in generating new files with extracted content. Somehow I could able to manage generating new file but unable to extract tags in between two specific() tags. The above XML is output of a third party tool.

Please share your thoughts or If anyone has idea to extract the elements between  tags?

expected output should looks like below:

File1.xml:

```
<modified>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <table><tr><td/></tr></table>
</modified>
```

File2.xml:

```
    <modified>
        <h1>Another Title</h1>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <table><tr><td/></tr></table>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <table><tr><td/></tr></table>
    </modified>
```

File3.xml:

```
<modified>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <table><tr><td/></tr></table>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <table><tr><td/></tr></table>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <p>paragraph</p>
</modified>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element_1">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1">
            <xsl:result-document href="{concat('File', count(preceding-sibling::h1) + 1, '.xml')}">
                <modified>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </modified>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: it groups nodes starting with `h1` and outputs it to a file name `File[no].xml`

Comment: It should suffice to use `<xsl:result-document href="File{position()}.xml">` to generate `File1.xml` for the first group, `File2.xml` for the second and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the response. @Joel M. Lamsen but when I tried the XSL in my system I got this error:    Fatal Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"
; SystemID: file:///C:/projects/XSL/XSL_Transformation.xsl; Line#: 8; Column#: -1
Error during transformation
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"

Comment: @kepler, can you tell us how you run Saxon exactly when you get that error?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am using Eclipse and added Saxon jars in to my project library. below are the jars I have in my lib.

Comment: Are you writing a Java program which uses Saxon 9? Which Api do you use, the Saxon one or the JAXP one?

Comment: Jar's I have in my lib are: saxon9pe.jar, saxon9-sql.jar, saxon9-unpack.jar.